# Enforcing Complex Password Policy in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

When enforcing complex password requirements in group policy, will it immediately expire any user's passwords who don't currently meet the requirements or will it let them keep their current pw until the next cycle (every 90 days) then make them make it harder? I'm pretty sure it will but just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no it doesn't apply the increased complexity requirement for current passwords, it will when they expire/reset.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875814.aspx